# PHP constant encapsed string php error

Tags: php

This is the error I am getting.
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in  on line 188"
What I am trying to do is connect to the database and insert data into the table, but i can't figure out this error.

```
$tableName = "customer";
$nullStr = "NULL";

$SQLstring = "INSERT INTO $tableName VALUES
            ('".$nullstr."','".$fname."', '".$lname."','".$address."','".$state."','".$zip."',          '".$phone"','".$email"')";
$result = $mysqli->query($SQLstring);
```

Comment: Hmm, okay, it's not really a duplicate, but you just have a super normal syntax error here: `$email"')";` Triple check that part.

Comment: String concatenation in SQL queries is **always** a problem for many reasons. You should be using a prepared statement with parameter binding

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the string concatenation operator `.` in a couple of places.

Replace

```
$SQLstring = "INSERT INTO $tableName VALUES
        ('".$nullstr."','".$fname."', ".$lname."','".$address."','".$state."','".$zip."','".$phone"','".$email"')";
```

with

```
$SQLstring = "INSERT INTO $tableName VALUES
        ('".$nullStr."','".$fname."', '".$lname."','".$address."','".$state."','".$zip."','".$phone."','".$email."')";
```

BTW, variable names are case-sensitive. You define `$nullStr` then try to use `$nullstr`. I fixed it in the above code.

Answer (score 3):

Use a prepared statement with parameter binding instead. Not only does it make this a lot cleaner, it also avoids SQL injection.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO $tableName VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('sssssss', $fname, $lname, $address, $state,
    $zip, $phone, $email);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some periods. Try this...

```
$SQLstring = "INSERT INTO $tableName VALUES ('".$nullstr."','".$fname."','".$lname."','".$address."','".$state."','".$zip."','".$phone."','".$email."')";
```